# __str__ method in Python

Tags: python, string, methods

I can't manage to get this `__str__` to work.
I created a class,

```
class Hangman :
```

and then

```
def __str__(self) : 
return "WORD: " + self.theWord + "; you have " + \
self.numberOfLives + "lives left"
```

there's an init statement and assignment in the program but I can't get the thing to work! 
the only way I can do it is by doing this, but surely what's the point of using `__str__`

```
def __str__(self) :
    print("WORD: {0}; you have {1} lives left".\
    format(self.theWord,self.numberOfLives))
```

Code:

```
theWord = input('Enter a word ')
numberOfLives = input('Enter a number ')
hangman = Hangman(theWord,numberOfLives)
Hangman.__str__(hangman)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Enter a word Word
Enter a number 16
>>>
```

using the print method, output:

```
>>> 
Enter a word word
Enter a number 16
WORD: word; you have 16 lives left
>>>
```

Comment: Define "can't get the thing to work"

Comment: sorry, it just just won't print like it's suppose to

Comment: Then give an example of actual output vs expected output.

Comment: Read this post -> https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-September/031726.html

Answer (score 5):

```
Hangman.__str__(hangman)
```

This line will just *call* the `__str__` method. So does this btw. which is the preferred way to do it (in general, don’t call special methods directly):

```
str(hangman)
```

`str` and the `__str__` method are just there to *convert* the object into a string, but not to print it. For example you could just as well log it to a file, so printing wouldn’t always be appropriate.

Instead, if you want to print it, just print it:

```
print(hangman)
```

`print` will automatically call `str()` on the object and as such use the type’s `__str__` method to convert it to a string.

Comment: Ahhhh! Can't believe it's that easy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Like this post says:  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-September/031726.html

```
 >>> class A:
...   pass
...
 >>> a=A()
 >>> print a
<__main__.A instance at 0x007CF9E0>

If the class defines a __str__ method, Python will call it when you call 
str() or print:
 >>> class B:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return "I'm a B!"
...
 >>> b=B()
 >>> print b
I'm a B!
```

Quoting

> To recap: when you tell Python to "print b", Python calls str(b) to
>   get the  string representation of b. If the class of b has a __str__
>   method, str(b)  becomes a call to b.__str__(). This returns the string
>   to print.

Answer (score 0):

`Hangman.__str__(hangman)` isn't a command to print the string representation of `hangman`, it's an expression that evaluates to the string representation of `hangman`.

If you type that manually at the interactive prompt, you'll get the value of the expression printed, because the interactive prompt does that as a convenience. Having that line in a script (or in a function you call) will not print anything - you need to actually tell python to print it, with `print(hangman)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
class Hangman(object):

    def __init__(self, theWord, numberOfLives):
        self.theWord = theWord
        self.numberOfLives = numberOfLives

    def __str__(self) :
        return "WORD: " + self.theWord + "; you have " + \
               self.numberOfLives + " lives left"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theWord = input('Enter a word ')
    numberOfLives = input('Enter a number ')
    hangman = Hangman(theWord,numberOfLives)
    print(hangman)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Enter a word word
Enter a number 16
WORD: word; you have 16 lives left
```